# Override price sorting to use max_price in list view?

Tags: product, price

In a category that's only listing grouped products with several associated products each, I'd like the price sorting to use the `max_price`. Seems like it's using the `min_price` by default.

Is there an admin option I'm missing, or would I need to go override a model for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override this method: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addAttributeToSort()`.
There is a section for price sorting:

```
if ($attribute == 'price' && $storeId != 0) {
    $this->addPriceData();
    $this->getSelect()->order("price_index.min_price {$dir}");
    return $this;
}
```

Change `min_price` to `max_price`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Marius! Works like a charm. :) For those interested: In your config.xml just add the reference to <models><catalog_resource><rewrite><product_collection>...